# How to parse api response on table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, uitableview

My json response data formate as :-

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Pradeep","name":"Pradeep","2":null,"sender":null,"3":null,"
```

So to parse the "name" on table view?

My own implementation is:-

I am new in ios development please help me

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData 
options:0 error:nil]; // response saved in allDataDictionary 

    NSDictionary *feed=[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"]; // feeds entry 

    NSArray *feedforentry=[feed objectForKey:@"entry"];

    for(NSDictionary *diction in feedforentry)
    {
        NSDictionary *title=[diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *label=[title objectForKey:@"label"];
        [array addObject:label];   
    }
    [[self JustConfesstable]reloadData]; // reload table     
}
```

Comment: Part of the JSON is missing...

Comment: NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
    
    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        arrResult = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
    }

Comment: Rinkal Rajoria check out my solution...

Answer (score 1):

First of all get data in Dictionary and then store what you want in NSArray.. using Keys

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    NSLog(@"%@",json);

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.firstArray);

    NSArray * responseArr = json[@"Deviceinfo"];

    NSArray * firstarray=[[NSArray alloc]init];

    for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
    {
        [firstarray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"name"]];
    }
```

first array contains names.. what you want from that json response.

and then pass that data to tablview. what you want to do here you get the array of name data.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",delegate.firstArray);

    NSArray * responseArr = json[@"Deviceinfo"];


what is delegate and first array ?? This produce error that undeclare identifier

Comment: i am declaring that array into appdelegate if you ahave an taht class array you declare direct Firstarray. and deviceinfo is my nsdictionary main Key..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON parser. I will recommend: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

With that you can do:

```
JSONDecoder *jsonKitDecoder = [JSONDecoder decoder];
NSError *error = nil;
id objectFromJson = [jsonKitDecoder objectWithData:data error:&error];
```

Comment: Any reasons to recommend JSON parser over JSONSerialization?

Comment: It was just a suggestion... I found it much more convenient to use than JSONSerialization and much better performance. Don't get why you vote this down.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is native so i don't think JSON is better than NSJSONSerialization

Comment: @Puneet http://www.bonto.ch/blog/2011/12/08/json-libraries-for-ios-comparison-updated/

Comment: The link is good. Thats what we need, an explanation. @GrzegorzKrukowski I voted it down because you recommended an external library without providing any reasons.

Comment: OK understood. Sorry ;) will do better next time