# how to display elements from json to table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

i am new in iphone development , i have an json response like :-`

```
(
    {
    0 = 1;
    1 = Pradeep;
    2 = "<null>";
    3 = "<null>";
    "friendship_flag" = "<null>";
    id = 1;
    name = Pradeep;
    sender = "<null>";
},
    {
    0 = 2;
    1 = Pradeep;
    2 = "<null>";
    3 = "<null>";
    "friendship_flag" = "<null>";
    id = 2;
    name = Pradeep;
    sender = "<null>";
},
```

i want to display all names on table view .
my code like as:-

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"Data from Web %@",allDataDictionary);


NSArray *feedforentry=[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"1"];

[array addObject:name]; //array will be display on table view .
```

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: i think this question is asked day before please chek out that answer and tried that code dont post same qn again..

Comment: no , problem was not resolved . so am still finding .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse api response on table view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717559/how-to-parse-api-response-on-table-view)

Comment: @RinkalRajoria did you get any outputs?

Comment: no , i have no idea :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSArray *getArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in getArray){
        [array addObject:[dataDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }

    [yourTableView reloadData];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks its working 

now i have a url
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/p?q=helo_users&u_id=5&page=1"];

in page=1 ; i want to pass argument in place of 1 . thanks

Answer (score 3):

i think you got the array directly from response so directly assign the response to array and display the names in tableview like below.

```
NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method you have to write

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is for display your array data in Tableview...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{



   return [array count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    //cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    /
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

get all names in an array and then do in your tableView Data source method cellForRowAtindex like this

```
cell.label.Text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return Cell;
```